# How to left join third table without foreign key

Tags: mysql, node.js, join, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables. One main table joins with the secondary table. But the third table doesn't link to the main table at all. Only secondary table linked to the third table.

**Property Table (Main)**

```
- listing_listtype(FK)
```

**List Type Table (Secondary)**

```
- id
```

**Residence (Third)**

```
- id
- res_list_type_details(FK)
```

**Here's the query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM property
LEFT JOIN residence
ON residence.res_list_type_details = property.listing_listtype
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a few rows of example data. Or, at least show us all the columns in your tables. It's hard to guess how the tables tie together just from a few column names.

Comment: Please give your DDL in detail. What does "link(ed)" mean? That there is a FK? You don't need FKs to join. You don't need same-named columns. You don't need columns from the same set of values. You don't even need the tables to be talking about the same things. Any two tables can be meaningfully joined. Constraints aren't needed (PK, FK, etc) to query. A FK says values for one column list appear elsewhere as UNIQUE. If not, not. So explain in detail what you want to do and why you can't do it, or what you are worried about and why it's a problem and why it can happen. Be very clear.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clarity in the question asked. I am assuming that ID column in Residence and Listtype tables refer to the same thing.

```
SELECT * FROM property
LEFT JOIN residence ON residence.res_list_type_details = property.listing_listtype
LEFT join listtype ON Residence.id = listtype.id
```

Comment: Don't answer an unclear question, ask for clarification via comments. If you can't comment, wait.